# Change and Extend Credit Card Expiration Years in Drop Down

Tags: checkout

Can someone tell me what the path is to change or add and apply additional years in the credit card "expiration date" drop down fields. We have a credit card we need to run that expires in 2023 and the drop down only goes to 2020
I need to extend and add another 10 years to the code.  But i cannot find the path in the control panel to add to the following code:

            Expiration Date *
            
                                        January
                            February
                            March
                            April
                            May
                            June
                            July
                            August
                            September
                            October
                            November
                            December
                        
                        
                            2012
                            2013
                            2014
                            2015
                            2016
                            2017
                            2018
                            2019
                            2020

Answer (score 1):

The logic in question is in `Mage_Payment_Model_Config::getYears()`. There is no configuration options associated with it so you will need to modify the function (ideally through a rewrite).